# Rspec not loading instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I had this working previous, now it mysteriously does not.   ruby 2.4.1, rails 5.0.1.rc2, capybara 3.6, rspec_rails 3.5, factorygirl 4.7 (2017 project)

The page controller (root_path) needs SiteCounter.find(1) (seeded), which factorygirl is doing.

If I run all 3 examples at the same time (or any combination of 2 of them) only the first one works, because for the rest SiteCounter.find(1) does not exist

If I run each one individually, they all pass.

```
describe "Sign In", type: :system do

  @site_counter = create_site_counter
  
  before do
    @fan = create :fan
    visit root_path
  end

  scenario "valid with correct credentials" do
    expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"
    find('#myNavbar > ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.signlogin > li:nth-child(2) > a').click
    expect(page).to have_current_path new_fan_session_path
    expect(page).to have_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/header/h3', text: 'Sign in')
    expect(page).to have_button("Sign in")
    expect(page).to have_button("Sign in").and have_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/header/h3', text: 'Sign in')
    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @fan.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    find('.dropdown-toggle').click
    expect(page).to have_link "Logout"
    expect(page).to have_current_path root_path
  end

  scenario "invalid with unregistered account" do
    find('#myNavbar > ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.signlogin > li:nth-child(2) > a').click
    fill_in "Email", with: Faker::Internet.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"

    expect(page).to have_no_link "Logout"
  end

  scenario "invalid with invalid password" do
    find('#myNavbar > ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.signlogin > li:nth-child(2) > a').click
    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"

    expect(page).to have_no_link "Logout"
  end
end
```

UPDATE

As per Thomas Walpole suggestions (I appreciate all your posts btw), I have modified the code to be more soft baked, and also took away factorygirl's task  of creating SiteCounter and added it into the page controller. I have also made the second two example expects more positive:

```
scenario "valid with correct credentials" do
    
    #fist LOG IN link
    within('#myNavbar') do
      expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"
    end

    #second LOG IN link
    within('.follow-login') do
      expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"
    end

    within('#myNavbar') do
      click_link('LOG IN')
    end  

    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @fan.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    find('.dropdown-toggle').click
    expect(page).to have_link "Logout"
    expect(page).to have_current_path root_path
  end

  scenario "invalid with unregistered account" do
    within('#myNavbar') do
      click_link('LOG IN')
    end
    fill_in "Email", with: Faker::Internet.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"

    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Sign in')
  end

  scenario "invalid with invalid password" do
    find('#myNavbar > ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.signlogin > li:nth-child(2) > a').click
    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"

    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Sign in')

  end
end
```

if this code is up to par I will move on to the second system test of 50 i need to write by 5pm.

=================

UPDATE

```
scenario "valid with correct credentials" do
    
    #fist LOG IN link
    within('#myNavbar') do
      expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"
    end

    #second LOG IN link
    within('.follow-login') do
      expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"
    end

    within('#myNavbar') do
      click_link('LOG IN')
    end  

    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @fan.password
    click_button "Sign in"
    find('.dropdown-toggle').click
    expect(page).to have_link "Logout"
    expect(page).to have_current_path root_path
  end

  scenario "invalid with unregistered account" do
    within('#myNavbar') do
      click_link('LOG IN')
    end
    fill_in "Email", with: Faker::Internet.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"
    expect(page).to have_css '.alert'
    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Sign in')
  end

  scenario "invalid with invalid password" do
    within('#myNavbar') do
      click_link('LOG IN')
    end    
    fill_in "Email", with: @fan.email
    fill_in "Password", with: "FakePassword123"
    click_button "Sign in"
    expect(page).to have_css '.alert'
    expect(page).to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'Sign in')

  end
end
```

this works and is as close as positive as I can get on this page, Mr. Walpole. `expect(page).to have_content("Email or password fail.")` caused a weird error that was removed only by deleting `<!DOCTYPE html>` from my layouts/application, as thoroughly outlined in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately your test updates don't really fix the issue -- You're already on a page with 'Sign in' button -- so in an asynchronous world that can match the page you're currently on.   You really need to check for something positive that indicates the login failed (and isn't on the current page).  Do you show a flash message on failure? Does the current path change? etc.

Comment: Ty. In my quest to stay positive I added `expect(page).to have_content("Email or password fail.")`, which is a bootstrap alert that comes and goes awkwardly, but am now getting `Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible xpath "/html"`

Comment: I have no other positive options, just that one alert. So I removed `expect(page).to have_content("Email or password fail.")` and added `expect(page).to have_current_path new_fan_session_path` due to time constraint, pending further feedback. I'm reading it could be any little random misplaced syntax error causing capybara to fail with this error, which could take months and months and months to find

Comment: if i remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` from top layouts/application the test runs fine, but who know what that does. I'm trying to trace the code through all the renders to find the faulty html or whatever, not seeing where devise renders the new sessions page. should be some kind of gem to scan code for faults like this, no? I'll check

Comment: ... according to a random post, capybara doesn't ignore the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which I find hard to believe.

Comment: I traced and inspected the path from layouts/application, including 16 random renders, found two rogue <html> tags, but it didn't fix it. I globally searched <!DOCTYPE html>, <html> and </html>, and searched through all of the files for weirdness. found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just set an instance variable and expect it to be used by your application.  Your application is run in it's own thread or process (depending on config) and won't see instance variables you set in your spec.

Beyond that your tests have a number of other issues

1. Your selectors are way too specific and will lead to very brittle tests.
   ie. Why use `find('#myNavbar > ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.signlogin > li:nth-child(2) > a').click` rather than just doing `click_link('LOG IN')` which also then obviates the need to do `expect(page).to have_link "LOG IN"` since the `click_link` would fail if the link didn't exist
2. Prefer CSS over XPath 99.9% of the time, it's faster, easier to read, and doesn't have the // vs .// problem
3. If run with an asynchronous driver (seleniun, etc - basically anything other than rack_test) then your 2nd and 3rd tests aren't actually testing anything. This is because `click_link` will return immediately after clicking and isn't guaranteed to wait for the actions triggered by that click to occur. That means the `have_no_link` will immediately be validated against your login page (which wouldn't have a 'Logout' link on) and pass, never actually waiting for the login failure to occur. Instead you need to do a positive expectation against something that should be on the page to indicate the login attempt has failed.

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you. ... You saying each example (scenario) runs its own process? I would have thought the describe was a process (not sure what a process is). Regardless, I acounted for rspec's lack of seeded object in the page controller, which passed the tests, albeit slower than when factorygirl was doing it.  I had them all working with the above code originally, can't figure out what happened.  click_link('LOG IN') gives me Capybara::Ambiguous: .... Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible link "LOG IN". Brittle = any slight change in design the rspec fails, w3rd

Comment: Whoops, 2 same links on page, will attempt first? and other such beginner tactics in a bit